# Detect end of conversation and ask for a feedback in azure Bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am creating a chat bot using azure bot framework in Nodejs.
QnA maker to store question answers and one LUIS app.
Now I want to detect end of conversation(either by checking no reply from long time or refreshing a webpage) and add feedback card at the end of conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by use of the `onEndDialog` method and the use of a separate class to manage the feedback process.

First, I have a component dialog that imports the `feedback.js` file and calls the associated `onTurn()` method within `onEndDialog`.

Next, I create the mainDialog.js file in which `MainDialog extends FeedbackDialog`. In this way, `FeedbackDialog` sits "on top" of `MainDialog` listening for specific user inputs or activities. In this case, it is listening for `EndDialog()` to be called. You will likely want to add additional validation to be sure it only fires when the `EndDialg()` you want is called.

Lastly, in the `feedback.js` file, this is where your feedback code/logic lives. For simplicity, I'm using a community project, `botbuilder-feedback`, for generating a user feedback interface. The majority of the code is focused on creating and managing the "base" dialog. Additional dialog activity comes from within the `botbuilder-feedback` package.

For reference, this code is based partly on the [13.core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot) sample found in the Botbuilder-Samples repo.

Hope of help!

---

feedbackDialog.js:

```js
const { ComponentDialog } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const { Feedback } = require('./feedback');

class FeedbackDialog extends ComponentDialog {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.feedback = new Feedback();
  }

  async onEndDialog ( innerDc ) {
    return await this.feedback.onTurn( innerDc );
  }
}

module.exports.FeedbackDialog = FeedbackDialog;
```

mainDialog.js:

```js
const { FeedbackDialog } = require( './feedbackDialog' );

class MainDialog extends FeedbackDialog {
  [...]
}

module.exports.MainDialog = MainDialog;
```

feedback.js:

```js
const { ActivityTypes } = require('botbuilder');
const { DialogTurnStatus } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const Botbuilder_Feedback = require('botbuilder-feedback').Feedback;

class Feedback {
  async onTurn(turnContext, next) {
    if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
      await Botbuilder_Feedback.sendFeedbackActivity(turnContext, 'Please rate this dialog');
      return { 'status': DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
    } else {
      return { 'status': DialogTurnStatus.cancelled };
    }
    await next();
  };
}

module.exports.Feedback = Feedback;
```