# How to detect end of dialog in Botframework v4?

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to kick off a feedback dialog following the completion of any other dialog in the system. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149147/detect-end-of-conversation-and-ask-for-a-feedback-in-azure-bot) which says to use `onEndDialog`, but that isn't a valid function in ActivityHandler, only `onDialog`. My "main dialog" is in bot.js extending ActivityHandler, which is why I am not extending ComponentDialog. Given how this is set up, is there any way to determine when a dialog has ended? I tried to check the dialog stack in `onDialog`, but it reads as no dialog for the welcome message and initial message from the user, and after that always reads as dialog running. Is there a way I can modify my function/bot handler to detect an end of dialog event? Here is the onDialog function I've tried.

```js
        this.onDialog(async (context, next) => {
            const currentDialog = await this.dialogState.get(context, {});
            if (currentDialog.dialogStack) {
                console.log('Dialog is running');
            } else {
                console.log('Dialog is not running');
            }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
```

I have considered adding an extra step to the end of every dialog to call the feedback dialog (likely via replaceDialog), but I'm not sure that would be a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a better solution, which builds on @mdrichardson's solution and addresses saving the dialogStack as mentioned in the comments for that answer. It's not complicated at all to save and check the previous state of the dialogStack.

Note that since the original question, I started setting some values in conversation state from `onMembersAdded`, so my conversationData should always be defined. Instead I check for `!conversationData.dialogStack`. For this solution, I also added an OR check for `!conversationData` which should account for having no conversation state at all as well as having a state but no dialog stack.

```js
        // Add this in constructor of your bot.js file
        this.onDialog(async (context, next) => {

            // Set up end of dialog messages
            const conversationData = await this.dialogState.get(context);
            if (!conversationData || !conversationData.dialogStack) {
                console.log('Dialog not started');
                conversationData.previousDialogLength = 0;
            } else {
                console.log('Dialog running');
                console.log(conversationData.dialogStack, conversationData.previousDialogLength);
                if (conversationData.dialogStack.length == 0 && conversationData.previousDialogLength != 0) {
                    console.log('Dialog ended');
                    await context.sendActivity('Placeholder for End of Dialog action');
                }
                conversationData.previousDialogLength = conversationData.dialogStack.length;
            }
            await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);

            return await next();
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

This can't exactly be done, since `endDialog` doesn't bubble up to anything accessible from `ActivityHandler` (as far as I know).

But for a workaround, you're so close! Change it to something like this:

```js
this.onDialog(async (context, next) => {
    const currentDialog = await this.dialogState.get(context);
    if (currentDialog === undefined) {
        console.log('No dialogs started');
    } else if (currentDialog.dialogStack && currentDialog.dialogStack.length > 0) {
        console.log('Dialog is running');
    } else {
        console.log('Dialog is not running');
    }

    // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
    await next();
});
```

Yours wasn't quite working only because `currentDialog` gets set to `{}` if it doesn't exist, which is truthy, so we need to check if there's anything in the dialogStack with `currentDialog.dialogStack.length > 0`.

`currentDialog` is `undefined` if no dialog has started yet, so `currentDialog === undefined` or `!currentDialog` allows for initial and welcome messages. Having those three separate branches should allow you to handle each situation.

---

Regarding "best practices", I'd say this is the *right* approach if you want feedback at the end of *every* dialog. If there are *any* in which you don't want feedback, it might be best to call your FeedbackDialog at the end of the appropriate dialogs.

Comment: This works as far as the messages I'm logging to console. But the missing piece is that it can't detect in this form when a dialog has moved from Running to Not Running. So I couldn't put a feedback dialog in Dialog Not Running because I could have done something without a dialog such as social talk call to QnA Maker. So this is instructive to find the current dialog state but doesn't quite solve the problem. Regardless, given that usually the business case will rarely be straight forward on when to ask for feedback, it seems that adding as the last step in the appropriate dialogs makes sense.

Comment: one further question, if calling a feedback dialog in the last step is it appropaite to just `return await step.replaceDialog(FEEDBACK_DIALOG)` on the last step, or do I still need to have an `endDialog` somewhere (other than in the feedback dialog). My assumption is no, since `replaceDialog` will pop the current dialog off the stack and replace it with the feedback dialog, but I want to make sure I'm implementing this correctly.

Comment: @billoverton Your assumption is the same as mine. [`replaceDialog` end the current dialog and calls `beginDialog` for another](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/f9e805b929a99d00e5c7a4ab27d4110ace5f348a/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/dialogContext.ts#L403). Since it returns the `beginDialog` call, it will bubble up whatever that dialog's final return is (which is usually `endDialog`). And good call about manually calling your FeedbackDialog. That seems the best approach.

Comment: @billoverton I edited my answer a bit to reflect that it's more of a workaround. If you really want to make sure a dialog just ended, you could save the `dialogStack` and compare the difference on each turn. I still like the manual approach, but this would theoretically accomplish what you want, too.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's quite clear now. I had thought about saving the dialogStack but that seems to be a bit overkill for the use case of calling a feedback dialog.

Comment: @billoverton Completely agree!