# Is there any way to know if Bot Activity response is a final response?

Tags: botframework

We need to know if the Bot Activity responses, more accurately, last response Activity, is waiting or not, for a user to respond on it. In other words, we need to know if an Activity from the Bot to the User is a final response.
Is there any flag or field on Activity object that it could be that we are looking for?

We mean, for example:

```
Bot: -Whats your name?  (<- Not final)
User: -My name is Edward.
...
User: -Whats the weather today?
Bot: -Today is a Sunny day with 23 degrees (<- Final)
...
User: -Benefits?
Bot: -Did you mean:
[What are my Benefits?]
[I have any Benefit?]
[None of the above]
(<- Not Final)
User: None of the above
Bot: Ok, could you please reformulate your question? (<- Not Final)
...
```

And so on...

Thank you

Comment: What do you need to do if you identify as final?

Comment: @billoverton Identifying answer as final answer its the key for a Proof of Concept that I’m working for. I need to redirect Dialog Flow.

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? Do you want to run another dialog at the end? If so, and if you are using waterfall dialogs, you could use `context.replaceDialog(DIALOG_NAME)` instead of `context.endDialog()`. But I'm not clear if that addresses your issue. It is also possible to check every turn if a dialog is running or not, and you could perform some action every turn a dialog is not running (implying previous dialog ended). But that could fire every turn if, for example, user is asking lots of Q&A questions.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Think that I have no access to Bot code, so I don’t have access to Bot Dialogs Logic. I’m communicating to the Bot using DirectLine so, the only that I have is a collection of Activities objects.

Comment: Ah, so I don't think there's anything on the activity itself that is going to help you. If you could peek at conversationState, you could check the dialogStack to see if a dialog is running. Reference this article here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955280/how-to-detect-end-of-dialog-in-botframework-v4. But that would require some coding... What you are looking for in a flag on activity itself I do not think exists.