# Conditional rendering of card vs dialog in this.onMessage handler botbuilder sdk nodejs

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

Inside my bot.js

```
    this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
        console.log("Running dialog with Message Activity.");
            let adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
            adaptiveCard.parse(welcomeCard);
            let finalCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(adaptiveCard);
            let outputCard = MessageFactory.attachment(finalCard);
            await context.sendActivity(outputCard);
        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        await next();
    });
```

I am rendering an adaptive card on this.onMessage. On click of one of the items of the adaptive card, a dialog is initiated which accepts some text prompt input from the user.

Now, whenever the user provides his input the this.onMessage is called and this adaptive card is rendered. Is there a way by which i can stop rendering this adaptive card while my dialog has not been ended ? I want this to run adaptive card to be rendered everytime except when there is a dialog running.

I tried looking at lot of documentation, but couldn't find any help there.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `setTimeout()` function to schedule code execution after a designated amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display your welcome card every time a dialog ends, correct? If so, you can create an onDialog handler to do this. However, you cannot just check if a dialog is not running because you will end up performing the action even on a response which is not part of a dialog (I discussed this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955280/how-to-detect-end-of-dialog-in-botframework-v4)).

```js
        // Add this in constructor of your bot.js file
        this.onDialog(async (context, next) => {

            // Set up end of dialog messages
            const conversationData = await this.dialogState.get(context);
            if (!conversationData || !conversationData.dialogStack) {
                console.log('Dialog not started');
                conversationData.previousDialogLength = 0;
            } else {
                console.log('Dialog running');
                console.log(conversationData.dialogStack, conversationData.previousDialogLength);
                if (conversationData.dialogStack.length == 0 && conversationData.previousDialogLength != 0) {
                    console.log('Dialog ended');
                    await context.sendActivity('Placeholder for End of Dialog action');
                }
                conversationData.previousDialogLength = conversationData.dialogStack.length;
            }
            await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);

            return await next();
        });
```

If you *do* want your welcome card to be displayed in cases where no dialog was started (e.g. I have a default intent that just queries QnA Maker without starting a dialog), I believe saving and checking `conversationData.previousDialogLength` can be removed. However, be careful with this as you will display the card **every time** you are not in a dialog, which you may want to do but just be aware that you have to choose between *when a dialog is not running* and *when a dialog has ended*, which are obviously different things.